# How to reverse Excel legend order?

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts, microsoft-excel-2016, data-visualization

I have an Excel graph (a stacked bar chart) where years are on the x-axis.

The problem is that the order of the legend labels doesn't fit with the order of the values in the bars as shown in the picture below.

[image: Image containing legend and bar chart, in which the order of the legend doesn't correspond to the order of the bars]

How can I change the legend order or reverse it ?

Comment: A screen cap of the table used to generate this chart would be useful to diagnose the problem

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad I resolved the problem. It was not linked to the data table. I simply changed the place of the legend to right and then to left so I got the desired order.

Answer (score 5):

As Karima pointed out : the solution that works is simple, although not intuitive:
Change the place of the legend to right and then to left (or reverse) and you get the desired order.

Comment: Both Left and Right had the reverse order for me, but changing it to Top and then manually moving & resizing it got it into to the correct order.

Answer (score -1):

This may help:

1. Right-click on the graph
2. Click on "Select data..."
3. Use the arrows above the series list.
   Note : it will move the graph's bars as well.

Here's a screenshot to explain. Let us know how it goes.

[image: Excel Screenshot]

Comment: l tried that methode but it didn't worked. It was not linked to the data table as well. I simply changed the place of the legend to right and then to left so I got the desired order